# Increase line spacing in wrapped inline maths

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, line-spacing, inline

I am using `\allowbreak` to wrap long expressions over multiple lines. For some reason, successive lines of maths broken in this way always appear without any line spacing. I haven't found any `\setstretch`,`\linespread` etc. that will increasing the spacing. Any suggestions?

Edit: example added below. This produces text paragraphs with a lot of spacing, yet the two lines of the maths expression are glued together. I guess this is consistent, in the sense that the distance between two base lines of the maths expression is at least the distance between two base lines of text.

So a better way to ask my question: in the example below, how do I ensure that the maths lines do not stick together, but have a bit of vertical space between them, without changing the line spacing of the text lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\everymath{\displaystyle\allowbreak}
\linespread{2.0}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
$\frac{1}{c_s^{2}} \partial_{t}{\psi_{1}}
\partial_{t}{\rho_{0}}+\frac{1}{c_s^{2}} \partial_{t}{\rho_{0}}
\partial_{i}{\psi_{1}} v^{(0)}_{i}+\frac{1}{c_s^{2}}
\partial_{t}{\partial_{t}{\psi_{1}}} \rho_{0}+\frac{1}{c_s^{2}}
\partial_{t}{v^{(0)}_{i}} \partial_{i}{\psi_{1}}
\rho_{0}+\frac{1}{c_s^{2}} \partial_{t}{\partial_{i}{\psi_{1}}}
\rho_{0} v^{(0)}_{i}+\frac{1}{c_s^{2}} \partial_{t}{\psi_{1}}
\partial_{i}{\rho_{0}} v^{(0)}_{i}+\frac{1}{c_s^{2}}
\partial_{i}{\partial_{t}{\psi_{1}}} \rho_{0}
v^{(0)}_{i}$
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: where is `\allowbreaks` defined?  it is not a command I know. Inline math will always break it doesn't need a declaration, display math will never break automatically in any of the standard packages.

Comment: Sorry, I meant \allowbreak, without the 's'. It is inline maths.

Comment: OK but the question is still completely unclear, inline math is just part of the paragraph so the line spacing is that of the paragraph so `\baselineskip` normally or `\lineskip` if the math does not fit in baseline space, there can not be any special spacing for just the math bits. It is _always_ best to include a small complete example document in the question.

Comment: I have added clarification and a minimal example.

Comment: the example shown _does_ fit in the enlarged linespacing (teh `\allowbreak` is totally unwanted at the position you add it though at the start of the math. it just adds a break point there, before the expression. the point of text style is to look better inline, but you have forced display style so it does look a bit over-sized, so it would be better to simply remove your `\everymath` setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX will ensure that *baselines* are equally spaced, unless the distance between the deepest object in a line and the highest object in the next one is less than `\lineskiplimit` (default value 0pt). Well this is not the complete truth, but it's sufficient for this case.

In your document the distance between baselines is set to 24pt, due to `\linespread{2}`.

The deepest object is `\frac{1}{c_s^2}`, which is also the highest object. Its depth is 9.33168pt, while its height is 13.20952pt.

Summing up these we get 22.54120pt, which is less than the usual distance between baselines, so no additional space will be added and the baselines will have 24pt distance between them.

Just to make experiments, try doing `\linespread{1.8}\lineskip=30pt` and you'll see

[image]

<sub>I added `\noindent` in front of the formula so as to avoid an overfull box that's irrelevant for the problem at hand.</sub>

Now the sum of depth and height is larger than the baseline skip, so `\lineskip` glue is inserted to distance them (default value 1pt).

Differently from other software, TeX does not implement line spacing by inserting a fixed amount of glue between lines: this would lead to differently spaced lines, according to the presence of ascenders or descenders. Rather, it works on a constant distance between baselines, until possible.

What you could do is to increase the values of `\lineskiplimit` `\lineskip`: with

```
\lineskip=6pt
\lineskiplimit=18pt
```

you get

[image]

which is as wrong as it could be. But the document is yours; adjust the values to suit. If you want also the distance between “rutrum” and the formula to be larger, give an even larger value to `\lineskiplimit`.

The problem is in the declaration

```
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

(note that `\allowbreak` does nothing at all, because it just inserts a zero penalty at the start of each math formula, which is useless or even bad). Such a declaration is one of the best ways to spoil the appearance of a document.

Just for comparison, here is the output without the dreaded declaration, and it looks quite good (considering the bad situation you're in with double spacing).

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction, the thing I was looking for was the lineskip/lineskiplimit combo. My example was of course a silly one; in the real problem, the output comes out of a computer algebra system and I definitely want display style. I am using inline math line breaking because the alternative for display style (breqn) has a bug which makes it choke on some of my expressions.